# Name to initials

Tags: java, char

I am working on this code which allows the user to enter a name which can include spaces and hyphens.

```
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    String result = "";
    char firstChar = input.charAt(0);
    char fUpper = Character.toUpperCase(firstChar);
    result = result + fUpper;
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char currentChar = input.charAt(i);
        char cUpper = Character.toUpperCase(currentChar);
        char previousChar = input.charAt(i - 1);
        char pUpper = Character.toUpperCase(previousChar);
        if (pUpper == ' ')  {
            result = result + "." + cUpper;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Initials Are: " + result);
    }
```

The problem i am having is the code to recognise a hyphen and include it in the end initials output

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement where you are checking for a space, also check for the hyphen:

```
if(pUpper == ' ' || pUpper == '-')
```

EDIT:

To include the hyphen in the output just do this:

```
    if(pUpper == ' ')
    {
        result = result + "." + cUpper;
    }
    else if(pUpper == '-')
    {
        result = result + "-" + cUpper;
    }
```

Comment: It is now recognising the hyphen thank you but how do i include that into the end output so if there is an hyphen in the name i want it to print out the hyphen instead of a dot

Comment: I just updated my answer with a code snippet that will include the hyphen in the output.